# How can I pimp my Jedi?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition

I've just joined a group, starting up a Star Wars: Saga Edition game, beginning at. Naturally, I picked a **Jedi**, and I've decided to be a **Zabrak**. The one thing that worries me is, *I'm not going to be as awesome a Jedi as I thought I would be.*

This is what I've rolled (after the +2 from my level):

- **Str** - 07
- **Dex** - 16
- **Con** - 10
- **Int** - 12
- **Wis** - 12
- **Cha** - 16

I know these aren't optimal, but it's what I've got. I'm going to attribute the *7* in Str to an **injury from the battle of Order 66**, but I'm not opposed to moving it around, and the GM isn't enforcing *roll in order*.

Firstly, I was expecting **talents** to be easier to get. At level 4 I only have two talents, making it hard to feel like an **iconic Jedi**, whom I've seen using the Block and Reflect talents ubiquitously. That's two talents that have an immense Jedi feel to them, gone already. And I'm not even thinking of focusing on Lightsaber combat. **How can I make the most of my Talents, and still feel like a *proper* Jedi?**

Secondly, on the subject of force powers. I will only be getting two, due to my low wisdom score. It feels like some are too good not to have, like *Negate Energy*, even though it isn't the feel I want, and **I'm worried I won't survive without it.** I've picked up Vital transfer, as we don't have any sort of party medic, leaving me with only one power left. I'm torn between either Force Slam/Force Push and Surge, as I was going to aim for *Form VI* lightsaber fighting. **How can I pick powers to complement my abilities, and style?**

I think my best hope it to use the skill *Use the Force* like a crutch and make as many things reliant on that as possible. I've noticed Force Perception, but I can't tell if it's going to be useful.

In summary I wanted to make a Diplomat/Knight style Jedi, but I'm worried I don't have enough Powers, Talents and Feats to represent this concept whilst staying useful to the party.

**How can I pimp my Jedi?**
*The thing is I will enjoy playing a sub-optimal character (~bad stats, few powers) but I don't know if my party will, so I want to make the most of what I've got.*

---

## Edit:

I've seen a lot of good ideas in the answers *and their comments*. If they could be collated I could assign a correct answer and my bounty!

Comment: Does d20 allow you to put a low attribute in a primary and thus change it to a 16?  If so, I would consider swapping the 7 for a 16 in Wis or did you ready do that?  If so, I would suggest asking the GM to re-roll (or pick) the numbers.

Comment: The standard array for this system isn't much better: 15,13,12,10,10,8 I think. I could re-roll but I think the DM would like to discourage that.

Comment: Hum... I can understand the GM not wanting in game rolls to be made again.  If you create a character that you will not enjoy playing (it's not what you have in mind), that is very likely to be useless to the existing party, and that may die in the first combat: why waste the time?  Just re-roll a new character now.  Can you ask the GM to give you the average state of each other character?  Then make a character that has the same average -- just pick the numbers. Note that your question *is* still valid but I do not know how to optimise this character since I don't know the system.

Comment: The thing is I *will* enjoy playing a sub-optimal character but I don't know if my party will, so I want to make the most of what I've got.

Comment: You've got a nimble, charismatic Jedi nursing old wounds mental and physical. From a roleplay aspect, I'd encourage  you to run with this. You may need to work with the DM some on scaling things: Yes, you have "Jedi" in your name, but you're more like Lando Calrissian with a little bit of Force power than an iconic Jedi. If scaled properly, you could have a fun running gag of, "I thought you were a Jedi!"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off:  If you want to be iconic Jedi, I'd say emphasize your lightsaber prowess.  Problem is, with that 7 crippling you, it won't be easy as Jedi more-or-less need all stats.

However, here's another idea:  Keep the 7 STR, and instead, become a Force-focused Jedi.

The Force powers can be massively powerful, and you should take full advantage of them.  I suggest changing your stats to the following:

STR 7
DEX 12
CON 10
INT 12
WIS 16
CHA 16

Now, at levels 1 and 3, take Force Training as your feats.
Bonus feat should be Skill Focus (Use The Force), maybe more skill trainings, or Force Boon (extra force point)
Also talk with your GM about making Diplomacy a class skill for Jedi, since I see no good reason why it isn't.  Be trained in that.

Next, talents.
Force Focus is AMAZING.  As a full-round action, recover a spent force power.  So useful, both in and out of combat.
Skilled Advisor grants any ally a +5 on a skill check, if you spend a full-round action.  Very useful.
The Telekinetic tree (telekinetic Power, TK Savant, TK Prodigy, etc) are also pretty good.

Alternatively:  Dip noble for a level, pick Exceptional Skill for UTF.  If you ever roll between 2 and 7 on a UTF check, it's now treated as an 8.  Every time.  It's stupid useful.

Powers:
Move Object is a must.
Negate Energy is a must.
Force Grip restricts enemies to a minor action.  Useful.
Force Shield is wonderful in a pinch.
Enlighten is maybe the most useful thing of all.  Roll a UTF check.  Congrats, you or an ally can use that roll in the place of something - attack roll, skill check, or defense, as a one-time switch.  If your UTF modifier is high, it's a godsend.  Sensitive, one-time thing, such as a diplomacy check, or disarming a bomb?  Roll Enlighten, and give it to the person.  If they roll better, great.  If not, they use your result.  Combine this with the above mentioned Force Focus and you are immediately one of the most useful party members.

With this, you've got a pretty damn powerful Jedi.  Iconic?  Not as much.  But useful to the party?  Hell.  Yes.

As an alternate idea, but you'll need to start it now.  Renew Vision + lots of Farseeing uses + Prepared for Danger.  Prep For Danger lets you spend a Farseeing use and regain any already used power as a swift action.  Renew Vision lets you regain all spent uses of Farseeing.  The other WatchCircle talents (see the Knights of the Old Republic Campaign Guide) are also immensely useful, but that combo right there?  you can't do it until level 8 at the earlier (as Prepared For Danger is a Jedi Knight talent), but when you can...hooo boy.

Also, if you reeeeally wanna optimize?  Drop Zabrak, become a Miraluka.  Free Force Training at first level if you're trained in UTF, which you will be as a Jedi.

Also also:  Someone on the Wizards forums went and made indicies.  So, so, SO very helpful.  Here's the link:  http://www.mediafire.com/?w7mlg0lq70gnd90

Wizards hasn't shut down the thread yet, so they seem okay with it, as the indicies don't contain all the specifics - just general stuff and tags.

I hope this helps!  I've made lots of Force Users in Saga Edition, so this is my area of expertise.

EDIT:  Since you asked, here you go:

Iconic Jedi are proficient in both Force Powers and Lightsaber ability - Qui-Gon Jinn and Obi-Wan Kenobi were both accomplished duelists as well as Force masters.

The problem here is that without being very high level, your character cannot be good at both, especially with those stats.

If you want to maximize your ability for both, however, here's what I suggest.  Assuming level 4 Jedi, with the stat build I gave you.

Talents:  Deflect & Force Focus.  Deflect will protect you from ranged fire, and you can work your way to the Praetoria Ishu talent which is from the Imperial Knight prestige class in the Legacy book.  That talent lets you use it on others.

Force Focus has many uses outside of combat, and is a good emergency talent to have in combat in case you really need is.

Feats:  Force Training, twice.  This gives you 8 Force powers to choose from.
Bonus feats: Skill Focus (Use The Force) and Weapon Finesse, if you want.  Take advantage of your DEX mod for your lightsaber, if or when you need it.

Powers:
- Move Object - no brainer
- Vital Transfer - good for healing, but have medpacs on hand as well
- Enlighten - the ultimate in helping the party.  Use it often, recover as a full round when outside of combat (or in combat).
- Negate Energy - just in case.
- Mind Trick - Another classic Jedi power.
- Force Grip - can more-or-less disable on enemy in a round, plus decent damage at lower levels.
- Force Slam - a good area effect power.
- Surge - the movement bonuses can be very, very handy to have

Comment: I really like having High Dex characters, but you might be right about swapping things around. Will this make using a lightsaber in combat pointless though?

Comment: Not pointless, but definitely a secondary option.

Comment: Additional note for flavour: Some use of deflection is supposed to be part of the Jedi's high Defence.  It should often be applied in the description for near-misses.  Block/reflect are supposed to represent being very good at it.  (I used the same reasoning GMing back in 3.5, when the deflect bonus was as low as +1 but Jedi had very high AC without it.)

Comment: Oh!  Right, I forgot something!  Take Weapon Finesse as a bonus feat so you use Dex with your lightsaber for attacks, not STR.  You'll still do rather measely damage (the -2 to damage from your lack of STR won't help) but this way you'll still be able to move it around and make attacks without missing most of the time.  Alternatively, take Kinetic Combat as a Force Power.  I think (I'm admittedly not sure here) that it lets you still use Block and Deflect.  If you still want a high Dex character, you can make DEX 16 and wIS 12, but that'll really cut down the number of Force Powers you get.

Comment: Sorry, last comment for now.  Other good Force Powers: Surge is a must, Force Slam is good if it hits but does middling damage at higher levels, Combustion sets stuff on fire (which does extra damage, plus it's an area attack), Force Light can really screw over Dark Siders, Fold Space is actually pretty handy in certain situations, Mind Trick is INCREDIBLY useful and you should have at least one use if not more, Mind Shard is good for damage and condition track, Phase is a wonderful utility power, Rebuke is great for other Force Users, and Vital Transfer, as you said before, is great.

Comment: @Tynam and Threads' if you would put this info into the answer in some meaningful way that would be great. Right now your giving me a list of powers but I have no idea which to chose to balance flavour and power (which was my original problem).

Comment: Not related to an answer so forgive the off-hand comment, but on reading the "...with that 7 crippling you...." remark all I can hear in my head is "Judge me by my size, do you?"!

Answer (score 4):

Okay so here is what you want to do for starters:

- Take move object, it is the most versatile power in the entire game.
- If you haven't already take skill focus: Use the Force, this at your level should bring you up to +15 on those checks.
- At some point take one level of Scoundrel to take the talent Fool's Luck which allows you to get +5 to any one skill for an encounter if you spend a force point.
- When you take your first prestige class that allows you to have a force technique choose Force Point Recovery to give you back the force point you will use every encounter.

All of that is in the main book for guidance. Do also take Force Training whenever you can, and increase your Wisdom as well when possible, and there you go, you have turned yourself into an unstoppable embodiment of the Force.

Comment: Fool's look doesn't stack with skill focus, this was modified in the errata. both, fool's look and skill focus are competence bonuses, so they cannot stack with each another.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is not worry so much about Cha

STR 7 DEX 16 CON 10 INT 12 WIS 16 CHA 12

your UTF checks should be bolstered by skill focus and eventually other things.

weapon finesse is a must here and you may look into battle strike or lightsbaer combat force powers to make up for the low strength.

Really, if you can get up on a pillar using surge or levitate you should eb able to fight off enemies from a distance.

Do not overlook adept negotiator for instance as a means to just talk an enemy down.

also if you level dip look into weapon proficiency pistols as your free proficiency. You should be able to hold a lightsaber in one hand to take advantage of deflect while shooting with a pistol at enemies.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to hold out for a few levels, get Weapon Finesse, and then once you become a Knight, use your first Knight talent take the **Ataru** form- this allows you to utilize your Dex bonus instead of your Str bonus for damage; it also this doubles your Dex bonus to damage if you're using two hands on a saber.

Until then, worry about **Weapon Focus** and **Weapon Specialization** in lightsabers. As for force powers, I'd suggest **Move Object**, **Ballistikinesis** (from the *Knights of the Old Republic* sourcebook) and **Negate Energy**.  **Heal** and **Heal Another** are also really useful in a sticky situation.

Answer (score 1):

Something I haven't seen anyone else mention yet:

Saga Edition is *very* multi-class friendly.  You could dip into Scout for Evasion, and flavor it as your deflect skill (it'll only help you against auto-fire, but that's common enough).  If your concept involves more of a force-wizard or diplomat type, you could level dip and get a nice talent from the Noble.

The low strength isn't that much of a hindrance.  By 4th level, your level bonus to damage will compensate for that, and as others have mentioned, there are feat/talent/prestige class combinations that will let you overcome it completely.

Rest assured, you'll get to pick from plenty of talents through your character's career.

Answer (score -2):

Block and deflect are good. Deflect, especially since all sorts of people have blasters. Weapon finesse would be good, as that would offset the str penalty. Skill focus UTF would be nice too.